# Why SRS signalling is used in 5g?

Tags: signal-detection, estimation, dsp-core, channel-estimation, channel

Since DMRS is also being used as a reference signal in PUCCH and PUSCH channel, so why an extra SRS signalling is required.

Answer (score 3):

Because DMRS is only sent if there is data to transmit and, therefore, narrowband while SRS, as the term *sounding* suggests, is not associated to any data transmission and also wideband.

For example, SRS can be used by base stations to choose the best portion of the UE channel bandwidth to schedule *next* PUSCH.